# Automating robocopy using powershell Invoke command - remote session

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, remote-server, robocopy

I want to automate robocopy through Azure powershell runbook and I am taking below steps but Its failing with access denied error for Source location. Service account used to create remote connection is admin user on both servers

1. Create remote session on destination server (using Azure Automation account runbook which is running on Hybrid worker )
2. run Invoke-command for ROBOCopy to pull data from source server to destination D drive.

Below code is not doing anything but runbooks status shows as complete

```
      $serviceAccountPassword = (Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'kvname' -Name 'secname').SecretValue

      $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('serviceaccountname', 
     $serviceAccountPassword)
    $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName 'destination_server' -Credential $credential 
    
    
    $scriptblock = {c:\Windows\System32\robocopy.exe \\source_server\Backups\ \\destination_server\d$\data\}
    
    invoke-command -session $session -scriptblock $scriptblock
```

I have also enbled-Psremoting and also added service account as admin to both servers

Edit : If I don't run as JOB I get access denied error

Comment: have you tried `enter-pssession` to see if it connects to start? also try running it not as a job to see what happens

Comment: Isn't Enter-PSSession for interactive session. After creating session I  added below  Enter-PSSession -Session $session                                                                
                                                                                                                                 and its give me error Enter-PSSession : The method or operation is not implemented.  If I don't run as JOB I get access denied error

Comment: enter pssession would be a stand alone thing, it won't fix your problem. The access denied sounds like your credentials are bad, and could be the issue you're having.